# Can the sound of infinitely long played music be decomposed in sine (or cosine) forms?

Tags: waves, fourier-transform

Every arbitrary waveform (except non-linear ones) can be decomposed in sine (or cosine) waveforms that spatially extend to infinity. That is if the waveform has a finite spatial extent. But say that I have a waveform that has an infinite spatial extent. Can the same be done for such a waveform? Say for the soundwave of a piece of music that's being played forever, without a beginning and without an end.

A sine (or cosine) waveform extends to infinity, so there is for every sine waveform a corresponding waveform into which it can be decomposed, namely the sine form itself. An arbitrary periodic sound can be decomposed in sine (or cosine) waveforms too (in principle). But what about an arbitrary infinite waveform?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform

Comment: How would you integrate to find the transform (coefficients)?

Comment: @user45664 You can integrate, but it will never stop. I can see now why it can't be done. Does the same hold if the form has an infinite temporal extent (but finite spatial). Or can you just integrate spatially for a certain time and then say that this solution holds forever?

Comment: The time variation does not show up in the integral--no?

Comment: Ultimately this is still better suited for mathematics than physics. At least they could probably give you a more satisfying answer with possibly necessary and sufficient conditions on the Fourier transform of an arbitrary function.

Comment: @Triatticus Yeah, I was thinking that too.

Comment: What do you mean by infinite spatial extent? I believe the transform is valid for any bounded function. Meaning there exists some value E which is greater than any value of the function. The function does NOT have to be periodic.

Comment: @geshel I mean a wave that extends as far as possible in space, while the amplitude is always bigger than zero. Say the wave belonging to music that goes on forever without lowering the volume.

Comment: Ok. Using the word space is confusing here. Because might this wave be 1D, 2D, etc. but that doesn’t really matter. I was off on my statement above - the function has to be not only bounded but have a finite integral over the absolute value from -inf to +inf. See the Properties section of https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform

Comment: @geshel Doesn't a sine function have an infinite integral over the absolute value from -inf to + inf. Which would mean that a sine could not be written as a sine?

Comment: Yeah I don’t understand that. There is obviously no problem taking the FT of a simple sine wave with infinite extent.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder you needn't take the integral over all infinity though, using the periodic nature of sine you can simply do the integral over one period and trivially you will of course get unity since sine is a basis function of the Fourier transform.

Comment: Hint: When you run Discrete Fourier Analysis on a finite-length sound sample, what you actually get back is the spectrum of an _infinitely long_ sound sample consisting of the clip that you gave it, repeated over and over again forever. But note! That introduces "artifacts" if the beginning and the end of the clip don't perfectly "match up." That's why, in many practical applications, we don't just feed the raw clip into the DFT; We feed in the clip, modified by a [_window function_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to admit that I have problems to understand your intention, therefore I like to put things together:

The Fourier series can describe every (infinitely long) periodic funtion. By the way, it's actually wrong that the Fourier series consists of sin and cos only, but it consists of sin(nx), cos(nx), and the 1-function. That is, because 1-function, sin(nx) and cos(nx) are a basis for all periodic functions. However, so far there are discrete elements (overtones of sin and cos).

Going from discrete steps to continuous coordinates ($n \cdot f \longrightarrow df$, and the sum becomes an integral) yields the Fourier transform, which can describe aperiodic, finite long functions.

What you want is now an indefinitely long, aperidoc function, correct? Such as $f(x) = x$ ? Hm... The integration is from $-\infty $ to $\infty$, but as far as I remember that is an effect of getting from sin and cos to complex numbers $e^{i...}$.

After some Google search I found this very nice site (but it won't help you most likely because it's in German): https://www.mathe-online.at/mathint/fourier/i.html. A very comprehensive overview about fourier series and transform. At the very bottom of that site they claimed that the Fourier transform is only good for functions approaching 0 "sufficiently fast" for $x \longrightarrow \infty$. But there is no proof provided and no info what "sufficiently fast" is...

Comment: Luckily I live near the border with Germany (I speak Dutch, which is almost the same as Deutsch). About my intention, I couldn't stand the thought that my "being" can be decomposed in sine-, cosine-, and one-functions. Sounds a bit crazy, but I'm relieved now! Thanks!

Comment: " but as far as I remember that is an effect of getting from sin and cos to complex numbers ei."What do yo mean by this?

Comment: The classical fourier series with sin and cos is from n=0 to infty, not -infty to infty. When you replace sin and cos by the complex exp, then you need to change to n=-infty to infty (which becomes later the integration limits when going to integrals for aperiodic functions).